# How to Publish ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework) with Visual Studio to FTP Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, razor-pages, publishing

I am trying to publish an **ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework)** to a subdomain on my webhotel. The problem is that when the site has uploaded and I visit [the page](http://www.me-web.nordatlas.eu/index.cshtml), the site is not displayed, only the code in the index.cshtml file is shown in the browser. The site consists of **Razor Pages.**

I have checked the root directory for the subdomain at my webhotel and noticed that there are no .dll files which I was expecting there would be. What might the problem be and how can I solve this?
[image: Publish window filled in]

Comment: Did you make sure the directory is set up to be an application in the hosting software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been informed by the support from the Webhotel Host that it is not possible to publish a Web Application to an ordinary FTP server. Instead I have found that Google Cloud Platform or equivalent, is needed to host a Web Application. The directory needs to be specifically prepared for a Web Application.